# Windows 10 update on dual boot delete boot folder?

Tags: fedora, windows

After updating my Windows to the version 10, my laptop starts directly in rescue mode. You can find my setup below :

```
1 disk (1To) : where /home /swap is mounted shared with Windows for data and cache folder
1 SSD (120Go) : where / is mounted as long as Windows installed
```

Something important : GParted show me 30GiB unallocated on the SSD and I suspect that it is the / of my Fedora (I don't remember exactly how much I put it in).

Things I tried, without success :

- `boot-repair` through live Ubuntu (if it can help : [the report](http://paste2.org/fbsyOhhD))
- [This technique](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue). Which is normal because I don't find any /boot folder anywhere.
- Using `testdisk` to analyze the SSD in order to recover the possible lost / partition (the unallocated partition showed in GParted) -of course I've ran `boot-repair` afterwards. To be precise I analyze the disk and then write as I read on several docs.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT :

[`sudo fdisk -l` on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/L3KJTvpD)

```
$ sudo lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part /media/ubuntu/Réservé au système
├─sda2   8:2    0  81.7G  0 part /media/ubuntu/D8C820EDC820CB96
└─sda3   8:3    0   450M  0 part /media/ubuntu/4C343C29343C1882
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 902.2G  0 part /media/ubuntu/data
├─sdb2   8:18   0  28.3G  0 part /mnt
└─sdb3   8:19   0  1000M  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   1    30G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1    30G  0 part /cdrom
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
```

Comment: Using your Ubuntu live, run `sudo fdisk -l` and add this info to your question please.

Comment: This seems to be a 2Tb drive. Please add the results of `sudo lsblk` as well.

Comment: I didn't noticed the 2To, I rerun the `fdisk -l` command and paste all of it on a pastebin. I'm sure it's 1To anyway.

Comment: Hello, @ToDo  do you have any update on that problem please ?

Comment: From the `fdisk` results your 120Gb drive (/dev/sda) does not contain any Linux partitions. Your 1Tb drive (/dev/sdb) has a 30Gb partition (sdb2). Look for your `/boot` there.